# syntax error excluding category from next/prev post links in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, categories

I'm having some trouble with syntax when excluding a category from the prev/next nav on single posts. I have it working but not fully how I want it to be.

For the next link, it's working 100%: showing the linked post title and an arrow. For the previous link, it's showing a linked arrow but the title is missing. I'm not quite sure where to insert category 7 in the previous post code in order to get it working properly. I've tried a few different spots but i keep breaking the page and getting errors...

This is how I have it now...

```
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'formationpro' ), '7' . '</span> %title' ); ?>
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'formationpro' ), '7' . '</span>' ); ?>
```

... what do i need to do to make the previous_post_link work properly and show the title?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kellie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title swapping only works on the second argument of those functions. You have `%title` in the argument for `excluded_terms`. Try this instead:

```
$previous_text = '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'formationpro' ) .'</span> %title'
$next_text = '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'formationpro' ). '</span>'

previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', $previous_text, 7);

next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', $next_text, 7);
```

Or if you prefer to keep them in your format:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'formationpro' ) . '</span> %title', 7 ); ?>
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'formationpro' ) . '</span>', 7 ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for your quick response. i tried both of those, and neither works unfortunately. they both print the 7 into the page and neither excludes category 7! i really need to buckle down and learn PHP. in the meantime your help is much appreciated! thanks :-)

Comment: Make sure that you are using the ones from the answer. I changed the formatting of the strings a little. There were commas where there should be `.` characters.

Comment: I had copied them in exactly - just double checked as well. still getting the 7s and no category 7 exclusion.

Comment: Ah, I didnt realize that was the exclusion argument. I updated the answer.